# .Net Maui 7 iOS push notification sound not working

Tags: apple-push-notifications, maui, azure-notificationhub

I am implementing push notifications with Azure Notification Hubs. So far it is working as far as the notification comes in as expected, but without sound (yes I checked to make sure my phone wasn't on silent ;).

My code:

Notification json:
{"aps": {"alert":"Notification Hub test notification"}, "sound" : "default"}

AppDelegate.cs:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        // Other initialization code here...
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound, (approved, err) => {
            // Handle approval
            if (approved)
            {
            }
        });
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        // Watch for notifications while the app is active
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new NotificationDelegate();

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

NotificationDelegate.cs:

```
    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14, 0))
        {
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.List | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Banner | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
        }
        else
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound);
    }
```

Anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You may try setting the sound in `UNMutableNotificationContent`.

```
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent();
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.Default();
```

---

You may try registering `RegisterUserNotificationSettings` in AppDelegate.cs.

```
var notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, null);

UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Its says that syntax is obsolete for iOS 10+ and to use UNNotificationSettings instead but i can't find an example of the syntax?

Comment: Have you set the sound for notification? Please see my updates.

Comment: Where do I use the UNMutableNotificationContent? That seems to be for a local notification and my push notification is coming from an Azure Notifcation Hub

Comment: If local notification is okay, then it might be an issue with azure remote notifications.  You could also refer to [How can I play a sound when a push notification is received on my iOS device?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1179206/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-a-push-notification-is), [iOS push notification sound stopped working using azure notification hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347310/ios-push-notification-sound-stopped-working-using-azure-notification-hub-no-so).